# Reprint options if invalid input

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a simple python script which takes the input from user and continues, for now it has 3 options and just exit's if there's an invalid input.

My question is what should I add to reprint the options if the user input's anything other then the numbers 1-3 ?

```
def select():
option = raw_input("\nSelect an option:\n [1]First\n [2]Second\n [3]Third\n")
if option == '1':
    print('Hello')
elif option == '2':
    print('Hi')
elif option == '3':
    print('Hey')
else:
    exit(0)
```

(Code just for example)

Comment: @ChristianDean my bad, you are right.

Comment: No problem @What. You could just repost your comment if you want to, or post another comment noting the minor mistake :-)

Comment: You may use a while loop. `while UserInput:` and `UserInput = input()`